# Copy a cell value from one sheet to another when a condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a google spreadsheet with two tabs, Sheet1, Sheet2.
Sheet1 contains two columns ID and Value
Sheet2 contains a column ID.
I need a formula where if ID of Sheet2 is present in Sheet1, retrieve the "Value" of that particular row.

With the following VLOOKUP formula, I was able to find out whether the IDs of sheet2 are present in Sheet1 or not. I need the help in obtaining the Value of the matched row.

My formula: `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE)),FALSE,TRUE)`

```
Sample Data Sheet 1
ID  Value
123  Apple
456  Samsung
789  Oneplus

Sample data Sheet 2
ID  Value
13
123
456

Expected Data in Sheet 2
ID Value
13 
123  Apple
456  Samsung
```

Comment: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A:B,2,False),"")`.

Comment: Thanks @BigBen it worked